# How to find existing service by Kubernetes C# client API

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, k3s

I have [KubernetesClient](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/) code running my app on K3s Orchestrator. I have created service `prog`, `prog-external` & `my-module` with specified Ports for `app-module` namespace which are now seen in **`kubectl get svc -A`** command:

```
root@Ubuntu20-VM:~# kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE      NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     PORT(S)                         AGE
default        kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.43.0.1      443/TCP                         86m
kube-system    kube-dns          ClusterIP      10.43.0.10     53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP          86m
kube-system    metrics-server    ClusterIP      10.43.4.133    443/TCP                         86m
app-module     prog              ClusterIP      10.43.175.255  9008/TCP,9009/UDP,9001/TCP      64m
app-module     prog-external     NodePort       10.43.108.249  9000:30001/TCP,9001:30002/TCP   64m
app-module     my-module         ClusterIP      10.43.23.30    9008/TCP,9009/UDP,9001/TCP      64m
```

Can someone please let me know that if there is any API in [KubernetesClient](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/) to find/get theses services ? Please suggest.

**PS:** I think API [ListNamespacedServiceWithHttpMessagesAsync](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/463e2d94dfe5a4bb54372aaab957ca8d794d767e/src/KubernetesClient/generated/Kubernetes.cs) will return all pods config for namespace `app-module` , **but** I only want those pods config in `app-module` NS for which I [created services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/#accessing-services-running-on-the-cluster) , here which are : `prog`, `prog-external` & `my-module`. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean  by `modules`? Especially what do you mean by `but I only want those modules in app-module NS for which I created services`? Did you mean Deployments or Pods?

Comment: @RafałLeszko: Yes I corrected the que. I mean to say pod's configuration here

Comment: You can look at the [Listing Objects](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp#listing-objects) sample code, if you want to "to find/get these services".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot fetch all pods related to services (in the namespace) with one Kubernetes API call (one function call in Kubernetes C# library).

---

You need to do the following:

1. List all Services (filtered by namespace/name)
2. List all Endpoints / Endpoint Slices (related to services you fetched in point 1.)
3. List all Pods (related to Endpoint / Endpoint Slices from point 2.)

You can think of the service -> pod like a one-way relation. So service points to pods (via endpoint), but pod does not know anything about the service

---

A more Kubernetes-friendly way of achieving what you want would be to actually label your resources. So, keep a consistent labels across your services/pods, then you list your resources by labels.